# Fusing the features of two classes and feeding them with the fused features

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

In the main class, there are two classes and firstly the first class is recalled and after that the second class is recalled. I want to use a module that receives the features from these two classes and does some calculations and finally each of the mentioned classes needs to receive the outcome of the module.

The idea that comes in my mind is that importing the feature of the first class in to the second class and after that applying the module in the second class but my question is that in this scenario it is not possible to import the outcome of the module into the first class.

For example for these two classes and the module class:

```
class first(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_planes=128, out_planes=64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=0):
        super(first, self).__init__()
        self.conv_s = nn.Conv2d(in_planes, out_planes, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride, padding=padding, bias=False, groups=in_planes)
        self.bn_s = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_planes)
        self.relu_s = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv_s(x)
        y1 = self.bn_s(x)
        x = self.relu_s(x)
        return x 

class second(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_planes=128, out_planes=64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=0):
        super(second, self).__init__()
        self.conv_s = nn.Conv2d(in_planes, out_planes, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride, padding=padding, bias=False, groups=in_planes)
        self.bn_s = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_planes)
        self.relu_s = nn.ReLU()
 def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv_s(x)
        y2 = self.bn_s(x)
        x = self.relu_s(x)
        return x
```

The Module class:

```
class module(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(module, self).__init__()
    self.conv1h = nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
    self.bn1h   = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
    self.conv2h = nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
    self.bn2h   = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
    self.conv3h = nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
    self.bn3h   = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
    self.conv4h = nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
    self.bn4h   = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)

    self.conv1v = nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
    self.bn1v   = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
    self.conv2v = nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
    self.bn2v   = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
    self.conv3v = nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
    self.bn3v   = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
    self.conv4v = nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
    self.bn4v   = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)

def forward(self, left, down):
    if down.size()[2:] != left.size()[2:]:
        down = F.interpolate(down, size=left.size()[2:], mode='bilinear')
    out1h = F.relu(self.bn1h(self.conv1h(left )), inplace=True)
    out2h = F.relu(self.bn2h(self.conv2h(out1h)), inplace=True)
    out1v = F.relu(self.bn1v(self.conv1v(down )), inplace=True)
    out2v = F.relu(self.bn2v(self.conv2v(out1v)), inplace=True)
    fuse  = out2h*out2v
    out3h = F.relu(self.bn3h(self.conv3h(fuse )), inplace=True)+out1h
    out4h = F.relu(self.bn4h(self.conv4h(out3h)), inplace=True)
    out3v = F.relu(self.bn3v(self.conv3v(fuse )), inplace=True)+out1v
    out4v = F.relu(self.bn4v(self.conv4v(out3v)), inplace=True)
    return out4h, out4v
```

The order of the classes in the main class is as follows:

```
class Main(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(Main, self).__init__()
self.first=first(the required arguments)
self.second=second(the required arguments)
self.features = feature_extractor()


def forward(self, x):
   
   x1, x2 = self.features(x) # as self.features, you can produce 128 convolutional channels
   x1 = self.first(x1)
   x2 = self.first(x2)
return x1, x2
```

My question is that how it is possible to import the outcome of the `module` into the `first` class. To be clearer, after importing the `y1` and `y2` variable of the `first` and `second` classes into the `module` class, how can I multiply one of the the outcomes of the `module` class with `y1` in the `first` class and another outcome of the `module` class with the `y2` variable in the `second` class.This is because if I integrate the `module` in the `second` class, although I can import the `y1` into the `second` class and the `module`, I cannot import back the outcome of the `module` to the `first` class and multiply it with `y1`.

> Update:
> I want that the `module` class receive the `y1` and `y2` from the `first` class and `second` class respectively but I have not idea how I should  integrate the `module` class inside the code. The image below can show clearer information about the idea:

[image]

Comment: It's still not a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also, indentation is all wrong! Please fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the program you've added is pretty convoluted, I've created similar classes to demonstrate the principle that will solve the problem.

```py
class first:
    # this class gives y1 in your example
    def __init__(self, x = 0):
        self.x = x
    def get_y1(self):
        # do any computations if needed
        print(f"x (y1) has current value {self.x}")
        return self.x
    def calc(self, y):
        self.x += y
        print(f"x (y1) updated to {self.x}")

class second:
    # this class gives y2 in your example
    def __init__(self, x = 0):
        self.x = x
    def get_y2(self):
        # do any computations if needed
        print(f"x (y2) has current value {self.x}")
        return self.x
    def calc(self, y):
        self.x *= y
        print(f"x (y2) updated to {self.x}")

class module:
    # this class takes y1 and y2 for computation and returns results
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def calc(self, x, y):
        return x+1,y+1

class main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.first = first(x = 5)
        self.second = second(x = 3)
        self.module = module()
    
    def calc(self):
        y1 = self.first.get_y1()
        y2 = self.second.get_y2()
        result1, result2 = self.module.calc(y1, y2)
        self.first.calc(result1)
        self.second.calc(result2)        

obj = main()
obj.calc()

'''
Output for this:
x (y1) has current value 5
x (y2) has current value 3
x (y1) updated to 11
x (y2) updated to 12
'''
```

This basically does the same thing as you're requesting: `main` class holds objects for `first`, `second` and `module`; a computation in `module` uses `y1` and `y2` from `first` and `second`. The returned values are then used to update `y1` and `y2` themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Because I condensed my main code into such a small code, when it comes to more classes (first, second, third, fourth and fifth) and considering that each of the classes have several lines for calculations, the proposed solution will increase the script lines in the main class. Do you have another solution for such a case?

Comment: @dtr43 how can you avoid _adding script lines_ in your program if you need the computation? Some sort of refactoring might be possible to reduce the LOC but that would be out of scope for this question